# ffmpeg aresample has no effect while it works in ffplay

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a .ts file which is missing frames 20 seconds into the file. I'd like to fill the missing parts with silence. This works using the following command with ffplay:

`ffplay -i http://tyberis.com/KFYI-AM_2020-10-30_09-05-26.ts -af aresample=async=1`

The same should work with ffmpeg but no silence is injected. Instead, the audio just continues playing. Example:

`ffmpeg -i http://tyberis.com/KFYI-AM_2020-10-30_09-05-26.ts -af aresample=async=1 -f wav -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 - | ffplay -i -`

What am I doing wrong?

Log:

````
>ffmpeg -y -nostats -loglevel trace -i http://tyberis.com/KFYI-AM_2020-10-30_09-05-26.ts -af aresample=async=1 -f wav -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 out.wav
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-2020-11-08-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-nostats' ... matched as option 'stats' (print progress report during encoding) with argument 0.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'trace'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'http://tyberis.com/KFYI-AM_2020-10-30_09-05-26.ts'.
Reading option '-af' ... matched as option 'af' (set audio filters) with argument 'aresample=async=1'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'wav'.
Reading option '-acodec' ... matched as option 'acodec' (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'pcm_s16le'.
Reading option '-ac' ... matched as option 'ac' (set number of audio channels) with argument '2'.
Reading option 'out.wav' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Applying option nostats (print progress report during encoding) with argument 0.
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument trace.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url http://tyberis.com/KFYI-AM_2020-10-30_09-05-26.ts.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: http://tyberis.com/KFYI-AM_2020-10-30_09-05-26.ts.
[NULL @ 000001d0e7bbd200] Opening 'http://tyberis.com/KFYI-AM_2020-10-30_09-05-26.ts' for reading
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] Setting default whitelist 'http,https,tls,rtp,tcp,udp,crypto,httpproxy,data'
[tcp @ 000001d0e7bc0d00] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001d0e7bc0d00] Address 144.2.127.86 port 80
[tcp @ 000001d0e7bc0d00] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001d0e7bc0d00] Address 144.2.127.86 port 80
[tcp @ 000001d0e7bc0d00] Starting connection attempt to 144.2.127.86 port 80
[tcp @ 000001d0e7bc0d00] Successfully connected to 144.2.127.86 port 80
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] request: GET /KFYI-AM_2020-10-30_09-05-26.ts HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/58.45.100
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: close
Host: tyberis.com
Icy-MetaData: 1


[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] http_code=206
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Content-Type: video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Last-Modified: Tue, 10 Nov 2020 19:12:18 GMT'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Accept-Ranges: bytes'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='ETag: "7c6a9e6895b7d61:0"'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Range'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2020 15:52:32 GMT'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Connection: close'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Content-Length: 6531496'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Content-Range: bytes 0-6531495/6531496'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header=''
Probing mpegts score:50 size:2048
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] Format mpegts probed with size=2048 and score=50
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] Probe: 7648, score: 41, dvhs_score: -2, fec_score: -2
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] Filter: pid=0x11 type=1
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] Filter: pid=0x0 type=1
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] Filter: pid=0x12 type=1
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] SDT:
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] tag: 0x48 len=18
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] new_program: id=0x0001
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] PAT:
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] sid=0x1 pid=0x1000
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] new_program: id=0x0001
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] Filter: pid=0x1000 type=1
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] PMT: len 21
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] sid=0x1 sec_num=0/0 version=0 tid=2
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pcr_pid=0x100
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] Filter: pid=0x100 type=0
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] stream=0 stream_type=f pid=100 prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] tuning done
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:7648 seeks:0 nb_streams:1
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] Skipping after seek
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] SDT:
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] tag: 0x48 len=18
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] new_program: id=0x0001
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] PAT:
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] sid=0x1 pid=0x1000
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] new_program: id=0x0001
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] PMT: len 21
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] sid=0x1 sec_num=0/0 version=0 tid=2
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pcr_pid=0x100
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] probing stream 0 pp:2500
Probing aac score:51 size:2640
Probing flac score:13 size:2640
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] Probe with size=2640, packets=1 detected aac with score=51
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] probed stream 0
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
    Last message repeated 11 times
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5014800 microseconds st:0
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31480] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31480] Address 144.2.127.86 port 80
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31480] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31480] Address 144.2.127.86 port 80
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31480] Starting connection attempt to 144.2.127.86 port 80
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31480] Successfully connected to 144.2.127.86 port 80
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] request: GET /KFYI-AM_2020-10-30_09-05-26.ts HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/58.45.100
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=6281496-
Connection: close
Host: tyberis.com
Icy-MetaData: 1


[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] http_code=206
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Content-Type: video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Last-Modified: Tue, 10 Nov 2020 19:12:18 GMT'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Accept-Ranges: bytes'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='ETag: "7c6a9e6895b7d61:0"'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Range'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2020 15:52:32 GMT'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Connection: close'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Content-Length: 250000'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Content-Range: bytes 6281496-6531495/6531496'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header=''
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] Skipping after seek
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] Probe: 763, score: 5, dvhs_score: 1, fec_score: 1
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] Probe: 8192, score: 44, dvhs_score: -3, fec_score: -3
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31580] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31580] Address 144.2.127.86 port 80
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31580] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31580] Address 144.2.127.86 port 80
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31580] Starting connection attempt to 144.2.127.86 port 80
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31580] Successfully connected to 144.2.127.86 port 80
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] request: GET /KFYI-AM_2020-10-30_09-05-26.ts HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/58.45.100
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=6266023-
Connection: close
Host: tyberis.com
Icy-MetaData: 1


[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] http_code=206
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Content-Type: video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Last-Modified: Tue, 10 Nov 2020 19:12:18 GMT'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Accept-Ranges: bytes'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='ETag: "7c6a9e6895b7d61:0"'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Range'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2020 15:52:32 GMT'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Connection: close'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Content-Length: 265473'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Content-Range: bytes 6266023-6531495/6531496'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header=''
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31480] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31480] Address 144.2.127.86 port 80
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31480] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31480] Address 144.2.127.86 port 80
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31480] Starting connection attempt to 144.2.127.86 port 80
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31480] Successfully connected to 144.2.127.86 port 80
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] request: GET /KFYI-AM_2020-10-30_09-05-26.ts HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/58.45.100
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=6281644-
Connection: close
Host: tyberis.com
Icy-MetaData: 1


[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] http_code=206
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Content-Type: video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Last-Modified: Tue, 10 Nov 2020 19:12:18 GMT'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Accept-Ranges: bytes'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='ETag: "7c6a9e6895b7d61:0"'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Range'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2020 15:52:33 GMT'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Connection: close'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Content-Length: 249852'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Content-Range: bytes 6281644-6531495/6531496'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header=''
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
    Last message repeated 88 times
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31580] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31580] Address 144.2.127.86 port 80
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31580] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31580] Address 144.2.127.86 port 80
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31580] Starting connection attempt to 144.2.127.86 port 80
[tcp @ 000001d0e7c31580] Successfully connected to 144.2.127.86 port 80
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] request: GET /KFYI-AM_2020-10-30_09-05-26.ts HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Lavf/58.45.100
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: close
Host: tyberis.com
Icy-MetaData: 1


[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] http_code=206
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Content-Type: video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Last-Modified: Tue, 10 Nov 2020 19:12:18 GMT'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Accept-Ranges: bytes'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='ETag: "7c6a9e6895b7d61:0"'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Range'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2020 15:52:33 GMT'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Connection: close'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Content-Length: 6531496'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header='Content-Range: bytes 0-6531495/6531496'
[http @ 000001d0e7bbe2c0] header=''
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] stream 0: start_time: 1.4 duration: 1097.98
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] format: start_time: 1.4 duration: 1097.98 (estimate from pts) bitrate=47 kb/s
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:329238 seeks:3 frames:117
Input #0, mpegts, from 'http://tyberis.com/KFYI-AM_2020-10-30_09-05-26.ts':
  Duration: 00:18:17.98, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 47 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100], 117, 1/90000: Audio: aac (HE-AACv2) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 45 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url out.wav.
Applying option af (set audio filters) with argument aresample=async=1.
Applying option f (force format) with argument wav.
Applying option acodec (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument pcm_s16le.
Applying option ac (set number of audio channels) with argument 2.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: out.wav.
[file @ 000001d0e7c06200] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
Successfully opened the file.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] Skipping after seek
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] SDT:
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] tag: 0x48 len=18
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] new_program: id=0x0001
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] PAT:
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] sid=0x1 pid=0x1000
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] new_program: id=0x0001
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] PMT: len 21
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] sid=0x1 sec_num=0/0 version=0 tid=2
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pcr_pid=0x100
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
detected 4 logical cores
[Parsed_aresample_0 @ 000001d0e7be5e80] Setting 'async' to value '1'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 000001d0e7beeac0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/44100'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 000001d0e7beeac0] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '44100'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 000001d0e7beeac0] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 'fltp'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 000001d0e7beeac0] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x3'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 000001d0e7beeac0] tb:1/44100 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:44100 chlayout:0x3
[format_out_0_0 @ 000001d0e7bf0080] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 's16'
[format_out_0_0 @ 000001d0e7bf0080] Setting 'channel_layouts' to value '0x3'
[AVFilterGraph @ 000001d0e7be6540] query_formats: 4 queried, 9 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
[Parsed_aresample_0 @ 000001d0e7be5e80] [SWR @ 000001d0e81bb8c0] Using fltp internally between filters
[Parsed_aresample_0 @ 000001d0e7be5e80] ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:fltp r:44100Hz -> ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:s16 r:44100Hz
Output #0, wav, to 'out.wav':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/44100: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 pcm_s16le
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
    Last message repeated 7 times
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
    Last message repeated 9 times
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
    Last message repeated 9 times
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
    Last message repeated 9 times
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
    Last message repeated 9 times
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
(...)
    Last message repeated 9 times
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
    Last message repeated 9 times
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
    Last message repeated 4 times
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
timestamp discontinuity for stream #0:0 (id=256, type=audio): 69892061, new offset= -71292061
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] illegal icc
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
    Last message repeated 7 times
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
    Last message repeated 9 times
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
    Last message repeated 9 times
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
    Last message repeated 9 times
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
    Last message repeated 9 times
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
    Last message repeated 9 times
[mpegts @ 000001d0e7bbd200] pid=100 pes_code=0x1c0
[aac @ 000001d0e7c0ed80] ChannelElement 1.0 missing
    Last message repeated 9 times
(...)
size=    5000kB time=00:00:29.02 bitrate=1411.2kbits/s speed=6.11x
video:0kB audio:5000kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.001523%
Input file #0 (http://tyberis.com/KFYI-AM_2020-10-30_09-05-26.ts):
  Input stream #0:0 (audio): 625 packets read (174267 bytes); 625 frames decoded (1280000 samples);
  Total: 625 packets (174267 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (out.wav):
  Output stream #0:0 (audio): 625 frames encoded (1280000 samples); 625 packets muxed (5120000 bytes);
  Total: 625 packets (5120000 bytes) muxed
625 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 000001d0e7c2e280] Statistics: 4 seeks, 22 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 000001d0e7bc9780] Statistics: 533494 bytes read, 3 seeks```
````

Comment: Save output to file and check. Share full log of ffmpeg run.

Comment: The logs show "timestamp discontinuity for stream #0:0 (id=256, type=audio): 69892061, new offset= -71292061". I posted the logs in the original text. The command lines with the URLs in the question also work.